# borders in converting from array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

I'm trying to learn vector class in c++.
To do so, I'm tryin to convert from array to vector form.

in **array** form

```
int find_recursively(int *a, int low, int high) {
    int mid = (low+high)/2;

    if(....)
        return find_recursively(a,low,mid+1);
    else if(...)
        return find_recursively(a,mid+1,high);
}
```

My convertion to **vector** form is like that:

```
int find_recursively(vector<int> a) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.size() - 1;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if(....) {

        vector<int> temp ( a.begin(), a.begin() + mid-2 );
        return find_recursively(temp);
    }

    else if(...) {
        vector<int> temp (a.begin()+mid+1, a.begin()+high);
        return find_recursively(temp);
    }
}
```

I tested it, and gives force close directly. I think problem is with borders, I dont get the logic of borders in vectors. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain "gives force close directly?"  And why "mid - 2" ?  This should be implemented as a function taking two random access iterators, not any particular type of collection.

Comment: consider `vector<int> temp( a.begin(), a.begin() + mid-2 );
` for the case when a.size() < 4.

Comment: Go through the code thoroughly, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

vector supports index operator, so don't use slices of vector as function parameters. Pass a reference to the vector and indices. Same stuff as with array, but with vector:

```
int find_recursively(const vector <int> &a, int low, int high)
```

and you can use a[index] (for example a[low]) to access your values. But if "high" == a.size, attempt to use a[high] will crash your SW. Always remember to check that indices are within the vector.

When you call recursively, just pass the same 'a':

```
find_recursively(a, low, mid+1);
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as written, will have a problem once your recursion drills down to vectors of size two or less.  At that point, your "mid" value is 1, and the "mid-2" calculation for a high bound in your first "if" block produces -1.  Also, your function leaves open a code path that has no return statement (if both "if" conditions evaluate to false).

You shouldn't be cloning vectors recursively like this, anyway.  You should be using iterators, like so:

```
template< class Iter >
int find_recursively(Iter low, Iter high) {
   Iter mid = low + distance(low, high) / 2;

   if (...some test of *mid...) {
      return find_recursively(low, mid);
   }
   else if (...some other test of *mid...) {
      return find_recursively(++ mid, high);
   }
   else {
      return (something);
   }
}

// call site:
find_recursively(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end());
```

Comment: `+` is only available on random access iterators. Also, `++mid`? You're skipping the first element of the second half.

Comment: I was assuming that your "if" conditions concerned themselves with the value at "mid" (as you can see from what I wrote in them).  Since I'm wrong about that, then you can omit the increment.  vector's iterators are, indeed, random access, and your function as originally written was explicitly depend on vector.  If you wanted to generalize this function further, you could either use something like the Boost concept check library to check the kinds of iterators you're getting or write some additional (tiresome) code to make it work with simpler iterator types.

Comment: With this conclusion `++mid` is justified. However, you don't need Boost concept, as long as the iterator derives from `iterator` one can simply use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).

Comment: Too true.  Thank you for the observation.

Answer (score 1):

`.begin()` and `.end()` are iterators, which provide a way to simply iterate through a container:

```
for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++vec)
    cout << *it << " "; // print the contents of vec
```

Note that `end()` isn't actually part of the container. Why is this important? Because it can be used to create a more general version of your algorithm:

```
template <class ForwardIt>
int find_recursively(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    const size_t length = std::distance(first,last);
    if(length == 0) {
        /* do something accordinlgy */
    } else if (length == 1) {
        /* do something accordingly */
    }
    auto mid = first;
    std::advance(mid,length/2);

    if(....) {
        return find_recursively(first, mid);
    }

    else if(...) {
        return find_recursively(mid, first);
    }
}

/* example calls: */
std::vector<int> vec = {....};
int result1 = find_recursively(vec.begin(), vec.end());
int array[] = {....};
int result2 = find_recursively(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```